# How to dynamically create a css style rule that is overridable by earlier rules

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have been using [jss](https://github.com/Box9/jss) in my project to do dynamic styles. This has worked great for the most part, but I want to do something it seems to not help with.

I want to be able to create a set of main style rules first, then create a set of default style rules that can be overridden by the main style rules if they conflict. Example:

```
<div class="mainClass1 defaultClass1">text</div>
<script>
jss.set('.mainClass1', {
  color: 'red'
})

jss.set('.defaultClass1', {
  color: 'green'
})
</script>
```

I want the outcome to be that the text is red, but the way jss operates, the text comes out green. I was hoping I could somehow create two dynamic stylesheets, the "default" sheet being first, and the "main" sheet being second (so that main overrides default). Is this possible?

**Update** - I confirmed a technique that works with raw javascript:

```
var styleNode = document.createElement('style');
styleNode.type = 'text/css';
styleNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(styleNode);
//styleNode.sheet.insertRule("#A" + ' { color:green; }', 1);

var styleNode2 = document.createElement('style');
styleNode2.type = 'text/css';
styleNode2.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(styleNode2);
styleNode2.sheet.insertRule("#A" + ' { color:green; }', 0);
styleNode.sheet.insertRule("#A" + ' { color:red; }', 0);
```

The element with id 'A' remains green even after the red style is added on the earlier stylesheet. Now I'm just wondering if I can do this with jss or if I need to roll something of my own.

Why does this not work?

```
var jss1 = jss.forDocument(document)
var jss2 = jss.forDocument(document)

jss2.set('#A', {
    color: 'green'
})
jss1.set('#A', {
    color: 'red'
})
```

Comment: "I want the outcome to be that the text is red, but the way jss operates, the text comes out red." Typo?

Comment: Accident, not typo ; ) - Fixed thanks!

Comment: insert the rules into a stylesheet appearing earlier in the document order to allow subsequent rules with equal specificity to cascade over your added properties.

Comment: Sounds like everyone has the same idea I had. How do I make that happen @dandavis ?

Comment: run this after you attach JSS: `document.head.insertBefore( [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("style")).pop(), document.head.firstChild);` or just prepend a blank <style>, set the innerHTML to your css, and don't use JSS. or maybe you can then mount the new <style> tag with JSS, never used it...

Comment: Ok I've confirmed that two separate stylesheets does in fact do the ticket - updated my question with some code i pulled out of jss's source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allllright, I figured out how to do it with jss:

```
<div id="a">A div</div>
<script>
    var jss1 = jss.forDocument(document)
    jss1.defaultSheet = jss1._createSheet()
    var jss2 = jss.forDocument(document)
    jss2.defaultSheet = jss2._createSheet()

    jss2.set('#A', {
        color: 'green'
    })
    jss1.set('#A', {
        color: 'red'
    })
</script>
```

I found out jss lazily creates its sheet. So if you want to ensure the order of the stylesheets, you need to create them up front with _createSheet.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using CSS selectors

You can do this very simply, just use the multiple classes selector:

```
jss.set('.defaultClass1.mainClass1', {...});
```

This has a higher class specificity than the `.defaultClass` selector.

---

#### Using the JSS-extend plugin

This [JSS plugin](https://github.com/jsstyles/jss-extend/) simplifies extending styles. For example you can do this (copied from an example in the repository.

```
var button0 = {
    padding: '20px',
    background: 'blue'
}

var redButton = {
    background: 'red'
}

window.styles = {
    button0: button0,
    button1: {
        extend: [button0, redButton],
        'font-size': '20px'
    }
}
```

This registers the `button0`and `button1` styles to the current window (just like linking a CSS file).

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for. I want mainClass1 and defaultClass1 to mix together automatically. If I wanted to write all the styles by hand, I wouldn't be using jss.

Comment: Then, why don't you just use the extension options of JSS? There is an extension plugin: https://github.com/jsstyles/jss-extend

Comment: Ah, looks like that plugin just doesn't do what i'm looking for either. I'm actually building a styling system. In that system, you can create style objects that are rendered into the stylesheet. Objects in the system can have default styles that they place on themselves. Because the normal styles can be created before the objects with default styles, jss makes the defaults override the regular styles when that happens. I'd like to use the regular cascading of css to mix styles together, so I don't have a billion different classes in the system.

Comment: Okay, then I give up, hopefully someone else can answer your question.

Comment: if you want to make a rule stronger, just add `html ` and/or `body ` to the front of the selector. i always give body an id of "body" so that i can bust out the super-powerful `html>#body ` prefix if needed...

Answer (score 0):

A brief inspection of the jss source leads me to believe that your answer lies in creating different stylesheets. From my brief perusal it seems that CSS in stylesheets created later override CSS in previously created stylesheets.

"Read the source"

Comment: That is exactly the idea I mentioned in my question. Does that idea work, or are you just guessing like i am? I tried out a test with creating two different jss objects that should each create their own sheet. It didn't work, so do you know how to make it work?

Comment: I see you figured it out. Your experiments confirm my suspicions. Well done. If my answer was helpful please validate it.

Comment: Well, to be honest, telling me "read at the source" isn't very helpful. Not to mention I had already done that, and in my original question I had already articulated the idea you wrote in your answer. So, no, sorry. Your answer wasn't helpful.